# Why is API HTTP response 406 despite not passing accept header?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, wildfly, httpresponse

My API is calling some other service with URL

`https://idgenvip.qa.ch3.s.com/IDGen/services/id/generate?idType=GIFT_REGISTRY_ID`

and this service is returning me **HTTP response code 406**
which is not acceptable.

> UtilHelper:691 - Exception occurred while generating  id : Server
>   returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL:
>   https://idgenvip.qa.ch3.s.com/IDGen/services/id/generate?idType=GIFT_REGISTRY_ID

I'm not passing accept header in my request. What could be the other reason I'm getting this?

Comment: Contact the server or attach an API specification

Comment: @yeahseol The API gives an integer. The response is in xml format.

Comment: *"I'm not passing accept header in my request."* -  Turns out, that was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case when I checked the code, The accept header was hard coded in the code itself.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

So when I removed/commented out the code the service stopped throwing 406. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To be frank with you, a 406 response *could be* returned for any reason ... or no reason at all.

According to the HTTP 1.1 specification (Section 6.5.6) it *should* be returned is the one of these headers is requesting output in a representation that the server cannot provide:

- Accept
- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Accept-Language

If the server implementation is following the spec, the response body should list the representations that it can provide.  (Look at the response body to see if it is saying anything.)

What else could it be?

- It could conceivably be that the server is telling you that you *need* to provide an "accept" header.
- It could conceivably be that the server is giving a deliberately misleading response, because it thinks you are abusing the API.

But I'm really guessing.  As I said at the beginning ... it could be anything.

My advice would be to read the API documentation carefully, and ask the people who run the server what you are doing wring.